# How to create a list inside Freemarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a set of functions_names that i generate while iterating a list of values.
I want to capture these values "functions_names" in a list and use it for further processing.
How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create another list that contains function_names you have generated ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FreeMarker doesn't support modifying collections. But if you really want to do this in FreeMarker (as opposed to in Java), you can use sequence concatenation: `<#assign myList = myList + [newItem]>`. Here you create a new sequence that wraps the two other sequences. Be aware that the resulting sequence is slow if you try to do indexed access in a long list constructed this way.